# How to use \IEEEkeywords

Tags: ieeetran, keywords

I am trying to have `\keywords` ... and used

```
\begin{keywords}

{

.

.

.

}

\end{keywords}
```

but the compiler keeps telling me to use `\IEEEkeywords` instead... but I haven't find a clear (and simple) example online of how to use it...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The environment is `\begin{IEEEkeywords} ... \end{IEEEkeywords}`. You can find online examples in [IEEEtran folder](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/) in CTAN.